# .NET Web API 2 and IIS PUT/DELETE not working

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

On DELETE requests to my Web API 2 controller, I get:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/phoenix/api/apps/1245 
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:404 Not Found

DELETE http://localhost/myapp/api/apps/1245 404 (Not Found)
```

my controller looks like:

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
[Route("api/apps")]
public class ApplicationController : ApiController
{
    // DELETE api/apps/5
    public void Delete(string id)
    {
        //apps.Delete(id);
    }
}
```

and my IIS is setup for the PUT/DELETE verbs:

[image]

and my web.config has has * for verbs:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `id` parameter is not present in the route template. Change your controller-level route to `[Route("api/apps/{id?}")]` maybe or supply the id value from querystring...